# Find the matrix of the linear transformation $T$

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix},C=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ and $D=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$. The images of these vectors under the linear transformation is $A^*=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix},B^*=\begin{pmatrix}2\\2\end{pmatrix},C^*=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ and $D^*=\begin{pmatrix}2\\3\end{pmatrix}$ respectively. Find the matrix of the linear transformation $T$.

Let $T=\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{pmatrix}$

$$
T(A)=A^*\implies\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
T(B)=B^*\implies\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a\\c\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}2\\2\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
T(C)=C^*\implies\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}b\\d\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
T(D)=D^*\implies\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a+b\\c+d\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$

$(2)$ and $(3)$ implies $T=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\2&1\end{pmatrix}$ but it's not satisfy $(4)$. Am I doing it in wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct! Note $D^*=\begin{pmatrix}2\\3\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I use $D$ as $D^*$, seriously why I didn't notice that. Thanks @dfeg

Answer (score 0):

The last equation should be $$\begin{pmatrix}a+b\\c+d\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}2\\3\end{pmatrix}.$$
The right hand side of the equation is $D^*$, not $D$.